# How to reset Object Identifier (ID) attributes in IBM DOORS module

Tags: ibm-doors

I'd like to reset (re-arrange) all the Object Identifiers (ID) in an IBM DOORS module. I inherited the original description and would like to update the ID tags to have a better flow in the document.

**Inherited**

| ID | Content |
| --- | --- |
| Req-55 | Content A |
| Req-57 | Content B |
| Req-14 | Content C |

**Wanted**

| ID | Content |
| --- | --- |
| Req-01 | Content A |
| Req-02 | Content B |
| Req-03 | Content C |

It's important to highlight that I'm fully aware that each [ID is linked to a database](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/changing-doors-database-id). I just want to try to figure out a way to have the ID tag better organized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never give the DOORS "Absolute Number" of DOORS Objects a meaning besides the numbers being unique. DOORS gives you next to no means(*) to manipulate that number to use it for sth like a "flow". If you want an identifying number that has any kind of semantic, you will have to create a new Attribute which contains a manually filled identifier. With this, the user is free to e.g. create Requirement numbers e.g. in steps of 10 so that he can later add intermediate numbers, like

| Manual ID | Content |
| --- | --- |
| Req-010 | Content A |
| Req-020 | Content B |
| Req-025 | Content B.1 |
| Req-030 | Content C |

(*) Well, if you really really really want to rearrange the objects as a one-time action and cannot sleep any more otherwise, you can only create a completely new Module, e.g. using Spreadsheet Export / Import, but this will result in the loss of all Links (which you will have to recreate somehow), all historic information like e.g. baselines, all permissions, possibly content like OLE objects and more. Prepare for nightmares.